# Unable to import despite clearly having the file

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, npm, importerror

I've been stuck with this error and couldn't fix it even after googling.

it says 'Module not found: Error: Can't resolve'.. based on researching on google, it appears that this happens when the import statement cannot find the file at the declared path.

But there clearly is a file named 'Button.js' in my `src/components` folder.

I am not sure what is wrong. Would really appreciate your help! [image]

Comment: try writing: ../components/Button.js , or drag + hold shift , then drop file near import statement

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried writing this instead:

import Button from "../components/Button.js";

It still gives the same error. 

The dragging doesn't work either. It doesn't allow me to drag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fix you could do is either exporting Button module as default in the end of Button.js file like

```
export default Button;
```

Or either import the button module in braces like :

```
import { Button} from “./components/Button”
```

If you haven’t set the base url as src:

As you are using relative paths and /components/Button.js is upper than the page directory so you have to use .. to come out of the pages directory and then read /pages/Home.js

So you should use ../Button.js instead of ./componets/Button.js

Comment: import Button from "../Button.js" 

is the one I tried and worked :)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
import {Button} from './components/Button.js'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it. I tried it but no luck :( it still gives the same error. Very strange.